# Python regular expression to match either a quoted or unquoted string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to write a regular expression in Python that will match either a quoted string with spaces or an unquoted string without spaces. For example given the string `term:foo` the result would be `foo` and given the string `term:"foo bar"` the result would be `foo bar`. So far I've come up with the following regular expression:

```
r = re.compile(r'''term:([^ "]+)|term:"([^"]+)"''')
```

The problem is that the match can come in either `group(1)` or `group(2)` so I have to do something like this:

```
m = r.match(search_string)
term = m.group(1) or m.group(2)
```

Is there a way I can do this all in one step?

Comment: Do you know about `shlex.split()`?

Comment: Can the quoted string contain an escaped quote?

Comment: I'm not worried about escaped quotes.

Comment: No, I hadn't heard of `shlex`, but the documentation says it doesn't support Unicode so it won't work for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Avoid grouping, and instead use lookahead/lookbehind assertions to eliminate the parts that are not needed:

```
s = 'term:foo term:"foo bar" term:bar foo term:"foo term:'
re.findall(r'(?<=term:)[^" ]+|(?<=term:")[^"]+(?=")', s)
```

Gives:

```
['foo', 'foo bar', 'bar']
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem that you really want `re.match` here. Your regex is almost right, but you're grouping too much. How about this?

```
>>> s
('xyz term:abc 123 foo', 'foo term:"abc 123 "foo')
>>> re.findall(r'term:([^ "]+|"[^"]+")', '\n'.join(s))
['abc', '"abc 123 "']
```

Comment: This also matches the enclosing quotation marks which I don't want.